# What's the most poetic way to translate this song line?

Tags: translation

"Ground control to Major Tom...". It's a very pressing matter, in that it relates to my own amusement. I hope I have met Stack Exchange's quality question guideline rules. Thank you.

Comment: The answer to this question is very much up to taste. How to translate a line in a song is a bit too subjective a matter to have a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Ground control" is *(sur)tera direktejo* and "(military) major" is *majoro*, and in both, the *j* is pronounced like the *y* in *yes*. However, it is better if the name Major Tom is pronounced as in English.

So the translation is ***Direktej' al Major Tom***. ("dee-reck-tay al Major Tom")

If you want it entirely in Esperanto, use *Direktej' al la Major'*. The stress is normally on the second-last syllable of a word, but it doesn't move if the ending *-o* is dropped: *ma**jor'***.

Answer (score 3):

**Bazo al Majoro Tom**

**Terbazo al Major' Tom**

Comparable - in a wide sence - with "base camp."

If you merge "zo-al" you get an interesting sound, just as "ground control" has interesting r-s. You could elide the final o in Majoro: Major' Tom.

Comment: Oni devus fuŝi la akcenton por kanti la duan version, ĉu ne?

Answer (score 1):

The most poetic way to translate a poem is to translate the whole poem. When you look at it this ways, the possibilities open up a bit. For example, since the first two lines are identical, you could take two lines to get the idea out.

> *Vokas vin la ter-staci'*
>
> *Ni vokas nun al la Major'*

My understanding is that Major Tom is not a real person so there's no reason you couldn't change the name to get it to work out.

> Ter-staci' al la major'
>
> Ni vokas al Majoro Tom

You could really call him anything you want.

I'm personally partial to Ter-Staci' - which is what I came up with after reading a few national language translations of the song.